# If $x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x-14=0$ has two real roots $x_1, x_2$ and two non-real roots $x_3, x_4$, find the value of $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

> The equation $x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x-14=0$ has two real roots $x_1, x_2$ and two non-real roots $x_3, x_4$. Find the value of $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$.

I took $x_1, x_2$ as conjugate pairs and $x_3$ and $x_4$ conjugate pairs but what I got was not enough to solve the question I then tried by trail and error and got 8 as the answer but I am highly doubtful about it.
Please if anyone who can come up with a proper method.

Comment: Hello. I took the liberty of formatting your math equations with latex.

Comment: The two real roots are not conjugate.

Comment: A natural starting point is $$24=x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3  + x_1 x_4  +  x_2 x_3  + x_2 x_4 + x_3 x_4=(x_1x_2+x_3x_4)+(x_1+x_2)(x_3+x_4)$$ but I cannot continue.

Comment: I think the intent of the question is to solve it *without* finding the roots.

Comment: @lhf I posted an answer that does not require finding the roots. Basically, it's due to the cubic resolvent being reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the Galois group of the irreducible polynomial in question is simply the dihedral group of order $8$. Unexpected thing such as $x_1x_2+x_3x_4\in \mathbb{Q}$, despite not being symmetric, can now happen!

Answer (score 6):

The equation is very similar to
$(x-k)^4$. You can derive this equation and check the similarity to your equation and $k$ comes out to be $2$.

You can then use completing square method to solve the equation.

$x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x+16-16-14=0$

$(x-2)^4-30=0$

$x = 2\pm\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{30}$ and $x = 2\pm i\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{30}$

You can solve this and the answer comes out to be 8

Answer (score 5):

I will provide a solution that does not require explicitly finding the roots,
but let's fix a misconception first.

If $f$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, then only the *non-real* roots of $f$ come in conjugate pairs.
The theorem is as follows:

> Let $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, we have $f(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $f(\overline\alpha)=0$.

Apply this to a real root $\alpha$, you get nothing.
This of course makes sense because you can have $f=(x-a)(x-b)g$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is an irreducible quadratic real polynomial.
Then $f$ still has real coefficients, but $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary.

---

Back to your problem.
Let $f(x)=x^4-8x^3+24x^2-32x-14$.

For any polynomial $g$ and a polynomial expression $h(x_1,\dots,x_n)$
symmetric in the roots $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of $g$,
we know that we can express $h$ as a polynomial in the coefficients of $g$.
This is known as the symmetric function theorem.
For example, if $x_1,x_2$ are roots of $x^2-ax+b$,
then we have $x_1^2+x_2^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2=a^2-2b$.
For more details,
see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) and an exposition article [here](http://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/gemstones/opal/the-fundamental-theorem-of-symmetric-function-theory/).

Now, in your particular problem, the expression $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ is not symmetric (for example, swapping $x_1$ and $x_3$ results in a different polynomial expression).
But also notice that this is not "completely asymmetric".
For example, swapping $x_1$ and $x_2$ does not change the expression.
This motivates us to consider how many different expressions there can be under all $24$ permutations.
Surprisingly, only $3$, namely:
$$
x_1x_2+x_3x_4,\ x_1x_3+x_2x_4,\ x_1x_4+x_2x_3
$$
As noted by @lhf, if you sum the $3$ expressions, you get $24$ because the sum is now symmetric!
Can we do better?
Sure, consider the following polynomial [1]:
$$
R_3(x)=(x-(x_1x_2+x_3x_4))(x-(x_1x_3+x_2x_4))(x-(x_1x_4+x_2x_3))
$$
Since $R_3$ includes all $3$ expressions,
no matter how you permute $x_1,\dots,x_4$,
the resulting polynomial will be unchanged.
Thus, $R_3$ is a polynomial whose coefficients are symmetric polynomials of $x_1,\dots,x_4$!
This means that we can express the coefficients of $R_3$ as polynomials in the coefficients of $f$,
thanks to the symmetric function theorem.

Let
$$
\begin{align*}
R_3(x) &= x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C.
\end{align*}
$$
Then
$$
A=-(x_1x_2+x_3x_4+x_1x_3+x_2x_4+x_1x_4+x_2x_3)=-24.
$$
For $B$ and $C$,
it's long when written out, but the idea is really simple (take advantage of symmetry):
$$
\begin{align*}
B &= x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}^{2} + x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{4} + x_{1}^{2} x_{3} x_{4} \\
&\quad +x_{2}^{2} x_{3} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} + x_{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{2} x_{4}^{2} + x_{1} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} \\
&={\left(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}\right)} x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}
+{\left(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{4}\right)} x_{1} x_{2} x_{4}\\
&\quad +{\left(x_{1} + x_{3} + x_{4}\right)} x_{1} x_{3} x_{4}
+{\left(x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4}\right)} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} \\
&= (x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)(x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)-4x_1x_2x_3x_4 \\
&= 8\cdot 32 - 4\cdot (-14) \\
&= 312
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
C &=
-x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} - x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{4}^{2} - x_{1}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2} - x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2} \\
&\quad- x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{3} - x_{1}^{3} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} - x_{1} x_{2}^{3} x_{3} x_{4} - x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}^{3} x_{4}.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
&\quad x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} + x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{4}^{2} + x_{1}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2} \\
&= (x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)^2\\
&\quad -(2 \, x_{1}^{2} x_{2}^{2} x_{3} x_{4} + 2 \, x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} + 2 \, x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4} + 2 \, x_{1}^{2} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + 2 \, x_{1} x_{2}^{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{2} + 2 \, x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}^{2} x_{4}^{2}) \\
&= (x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)^2 \\
&\quad - 2\,  x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}{\left(x_{1} x_{2} + x_{1} x_{3} + x_{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{4} + x_{2} x_{4} + x_{3} x_{4}\right)} \\
&= 32^2-2\cdot (-14)\cdot 24 \\
&= 1696
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
&\quad x_{1}^{3} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{2}^{3} x_{3} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{2} x_{3}^{3} x_{4} + x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}^{3} \\
&= x_{1} x_{2} x_{3} x_{4}{\left(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} + x_{4}^{2}\right)}  \\
&= x_1x_2x_3x_4 \\
&\quad \cdot ((x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^2- 2\,  {\left(x_{1} x_{2} + x_{1} x_{3} + x_{2} x_{3} + x_{1} x_{4} + x_{2} x_{4} + x_{3} x_{4}\right)}) \\
&= -14\cdot (8^2-2\cdot 24) \\
&= -224
\end{align*}
$$

Substituting this back into $C$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
C = -1696 - (-224) = -1472.
\end{align*}
$$

The dust settles,
and we are left with:
$$
R_3(x) = x^3-24x^2+312x-1472.
$$
We want to see if we can factorize $R_3$.
We can see if there is a rational root of $R_3$.
By rational root theorem,
any rational root must be a divisor of $1472=2^6\cdot 23$,
and hence an integer.
If $\alpha$ is a such a root, then we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha^3&\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ 2) \\
\alpha^3-2&\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ 3) \\
\alpha^3-\alpha^2+2\alpha-2&\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ 5)
\end{align*}
$$
After a few testings, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha&\equiv 0\ (\text{mod}\ 2) \\
\alpha&\equiv 2\ (\text{mod}\ 3) \\
\alpha&\equiv 3\ (\text{mod}\ 5)
\end{align*}
$$
Using Chinese remainder theorem, it's not hard to find that
the smallest positive solution is $\alpha=8$,
which happens to be a root of $R_3$!

Then we have
$$
R_3(x)={\left(x - 8\right)}{\left(x^{2} - 16 \, x + 184\right)}.
$$
The discriminant of the quadratic factor is $16^2-4\cdot 184=-480<0$,
so $x=8$ is the only real root of $R_3$.

Finally, recall that the roots of $R_3$ are:
$$
x_1x_2+x_3x_4,\ x_1x_3+x_2x_4,\ x_1x_4+x_2x_3
$$
Since we know that $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ is real,
it has to be the unique real root of $R_3$,
so we have $x_1x_2+x_3x_4=8$.

---

[1]: This is known as the [cubic resolvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic) of $f$. If you know a little Galois theory, you will immediately see that the coefficients of $R_3$ can be expressed as polynomials of coefficients of $f$.

Comment: (+1) I worked it essentially the same way and got $(x-(ab+cd))(x-(ac+bd))(x-(ad+bc))=x^3-\beta x^2+\left(\alpha\gamma-4\delta\right)x-\left(\gamma^2+\alpha^2\delta-4\beta\delta\right)$ where $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are roots of $x^4+\alpha x^3+\beta x^2+\gamma x+\delta$

Comment: As in your answer, this gives $x^3-24x^2+312x-1472=(x-8)\left((x-8)^2+120\right)$

Answer (score 1):

It might be remarked that if one missed the "binomial-fourth-power" coefficients in $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^4 - 8x^3 + 24x^2 - 32x - 14 \ \ $ (which leads to **Vinanth S Bharadwaj**'s very direct argument), "depressing" the polynomial takes us to a similar place:
$$ f(x+2) \ \ = \ \ F(y) \ \ = \ \ y^4 \ - \ 30 \ \ , $$
for which the zeroes are arranged on the real and imaginary axes at a radius $ \ \rho \ \ . \ $  While it is easy to obtain $ \ \rho \ = \ 30^{1/4} \ \ , \ $ we don't actually care what its value is.  Returning to $ \ f(x) \ \ , \ $ we find that the products of the real and imaginary zeroes are $ \ x_1·x_2 \ = \ (2 + \rho)·(2 - \rho) \ = \ 4 - \rho^2 \ \ $ and $ \ x_3·x_4 \ = \ (2 + i\rho)·(2 - i\rho) $ $ = \ 4 + \rho^2 \ \ . \  $  The sum we seek is then $ \ x_1x_2 \ + \ x_3x_4 \ = \ 8 \ \ . $

Going to somewhat more trouble, we could use the complex-conjugacy of $ \ x_3 \ , \ x_4 = \overline{x_3} \ = \ \gamma \pm i·\delta \ \ $ to write two quadratic factors for $ \ f(x) \ = \ (x^2 + ax + b)·(x^2 - 2·\gamma·x + c) \ \ , \ $ with  $ \ c \ = \ z_{3,4}·\overline{z_{3,4} } \ \ . $  Without presenting the ensuing calculations for a system of four equations, we obtain
$$ f(x) \ = \ (x^2 - 4x + 4 - \sqrt{30})·(x^2 - 4x + 4 + \sqrt{30}) \ \ . $$
Once again, we don't need to determine the zeroes, but can simply observe that $ \ x_1·x_2 \ $ and $ \ x_3·x_4 \ $ are equal to the constant terms of these factors (we won't even need to say which pair* corresponds to which constant).  The sum of said constant terms is $ \ 8 \ \ . $

$ \ ^{*} $ though we see that the second factor is irreducible over $ \ \mathbb{R} \ . $

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, the following is a computer-aided way to brute force it.

Let $\,x_3 = z\,$ be one of the (non-real) complex roots, and let $\,t=|z|^2 \ge 0\,$. Because the polynomial has real coefficients, the other complex root is $\,x_4=\bar z =\dfrac{t}{z}\,$. Therefore the equalities hold true:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
\;\; z^4 - 8 z^3 + 24 z^2 - 32 z - 14 &= 0
\\ \;\; t^4 - 8 t^3 z + 24 t^2 z^2 - 32 t z^3 - 14 z^4 &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases} \tag{*}
$$

Eliminating $\,z\,$ between the two equations using polynomial [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) gives (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28z%5E4+-+8+z%5E3+%2B+24+z%5E2+-+32+z+-+14%2C+t%5E4+-+8+t%5E3+z+%2B+24+t%5E2+z%5E2+-+32+t+z%5E3+-+14+z%5E4%2C+z%29)):

$$
(t^2 - 8 t - 14)^2 (t^4 - 16 t^3 + 36 t^2 - 1696 t + 196) (t^4 - 16 t^3 + 156 t^2 + 224 t + 196)^2 = 0
$$

Since equations $(*)$ have two roots in common, $z$ and $\bar z$, $\,t\,$ must be a double root of the resultant. The last factor has no real roots, so $\,t\,$ must be a root of the quadratic factor i.e. $\,t=4 \pm \sqrt{30}\,$, and $\,t \ge 0 \implies t = 4 + \sqrt{30}\,$.

Then from Vieta's relations $\,x_1x_2 = -\dfrac{14}{x_3x_4}=-\dfrac{14}{t}=-\dfrac{14}{4+\sqrt{30}}=4-\sqrt{30}\,$, and therefore $\,x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ $\require{cancel}= (4-\cancel{\sqrt{30}})+(4+\cancel{\sqrt{30}})=8\,$.